# How to set the distance between the halfway label and arrow in tikz?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-node

I know that I can use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to node[midway, above=..., left=..., rotate=45] {A} (1,1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to set the position of the label, but it is very tedious to calculate the correct position, and when the rotate angle changed, I may need to recalculate the position. Is there an easier way to set the distance between label and arrow?

Comment: You can use [sloped]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

BTW, I apologize for some gratuitous changes, but I find it easier to draw the line first, then add the labels.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node[midway, above, sloped] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: IMHO your suggestion to put the label after the path is not necessarily a good one. True, in *this* case it works, but in general it won't. Compare `\draw (0,-2) to[bend left] (2,-2) node[midway, above, sloped] {A} ;` to `\draw (0,-2) to[bend left] node[midway, above, sloped] {A}  (2,-2);`. What you are doing here is certainly not wrong but I personally would refrain from calling your prescription "easier" because it cannot be used in path constructions that are not just `--`.

Comment: @marmot - More precisely, I find it easier to read if I don't have to wade thorough all the node(s) before locating the endpoint.  (BTW, is sloped even defined for curved lines?)

Comment: Yes, `sloped` is defined, try e.g. `\draw (0,0) to[out=90,in=180] node[midway, above, sloped] {A} ++ (2,2);` and compare this to `\draw (0,0) to[out=90,in=180] ++ (2,2) node[midway, above, sloped] {A} ;`.

Comment: @marmot - Ah, the problem isn't with `sloped` or `bend`, it is with `to` and `midway` (or any `pos`).

Answer (score 2):

With the library `positioning`, you can choose any distance you like after `above left=`, please note the `and` between the two distances.

Of course, you could use also `above` or `left` alone, and also `below`, `right` or a combination of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0) to node[midway, above left=3ex and 1em, rotate=45] {A} (1,1) ; \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]